# Expanding List? (android)

Tags: android

So i want to make a list that has a number of items on the list but when a item is clicked i would like it to expand in the list to revile more information

i have done something similar with java script before but searching google isnt helping me :(

Does any one know a way i can achieve this or will i be stuck using multiple pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for Expandable listView. You can check the example [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html)
Hope this  may help u..